# Is there a way to get a list of all classes from a .dex file?

Tags: java, android, class, dex, dx

I have a `.dex` file, call it `classes.dex`.

Is there a way to "read" the contents of that `classes.dex` and get a list of all classes in there as full class names, including their package, `com.mypackage.mysubpackage.MyClass`, for exmaple?

I was thinking about [`com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/google/android/tools/dx/1.7/dx-1.7-javadoc.jar!/com/android/dx/dex/file/DexFile.html), but I cannot seem to find a method for retrieving an entire set of classes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [dexlib2 library](https://code.google.com/p/smali/source/browse/#git/dexlib/src/main/java/org/jf/dexlib) as a standalone library ([available in maven](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.smali%7Cdexlib2%7C2.0.3%7Cjar)), to read the dex file and get a list of classes.

```
DexFile dexFile = DexFileFactory.loadDexFile("classes.dex", 19 /*api level*/);
for (ClassDef classDef: dexFile.getClasses()) {
    System.out.println(classDef.getType());
}
```

Note that the class names will be of the form "Ljava/lang/String;", which is how they are stored in the dex file (and in a java class file). To convert, just remove the first and last letter, and replace / with .

Comment: Actually, .class files are inconsistent with how classes are named in them. Sometimes they have the "L...;" form and sometimes it's just the  name (but with slashes not dots).

Comment: Interesting! Didn't know that.

Comment: Hey JesusFreke, you have a one character typo: it should be classdef.getType() instead of classDef.getType(). Thanks!

Answer (score 125):

Use the command line tool `dexdump` from the Android-SDK. It's in `$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/<some_version>/dexdump`. It prints a lot more info than you probably want. I didn't find a way to make `dexdump` less verbose, but

```
dexdump classes.dex | grep 'Class descriptor'
```

should work.

Comment: I don't know if this is an OSX thing or if it's just because I have a different ADT version... but for me the dexdump tool is in sdk/build-tools/<some_version>/ rather than under platform-tools/.

Comment: `dexdump classes.dex | findstr 'Class descriptor'` under windows.

Comment: # this is what I did on my Mac to use the latests dexdump
sudo ln -s /source/android-sdks/build-tools/21.1.2/dexdump /usr/local/bin/dexdump

Comment: @naXa How to use this command? Where should the classes.dex be localed? - I can't fint it anywhere.

Comment: @MortenHolmgaard, in the current directory. classes.dex is packed inside apk file. Extract it, `cd` to the directory, where you have extracted it, and execute the command (in PowerShell).

Comment: Usage: dexdump: [-c] [-d] [-f] [-h] [-i] [-l layout] [-m] [-t tempfile] dexfile...  
     
 -c : verify checksum and exit  -d : disassemble code sections   
 -f : display summary information from file header   
 -h : display file header details   
 -i : ignore checksum failures   
 -l : output layout, either 'plain' or 'xml'   
 -m : dump register maps (and nothing else)   
 -t : temp file name (defaults to /sdcard/dex-temp-*)

Comment: @csmu that's an interesting way to append a directory to `PATH`

Comment: @MortenHolmgaard you can get the 'classes.dex' file by unpacking your apk file using 'tar -xvf <apkFile>'.

Comment: You can find the 'dexdump' executable in '<android-sdk-dir>/build-tools/<version>/'

Comment: This has now moved to `platform-tools/(version)/dexdump`.

Comment: If you get `ERROR: Failed structural verification of 'classes.dex'`. You may be using a build tools version that's too old. I had to use `Android/sdk/build-tools/30.0.2/dexdump` instead of `Android/sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/dexdump`

Answer (score 12):

You can use `dex2jar` utility that will convert `.dex` to `.jar.`

http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/

Then you can extract that `.jar` file.

Also , you can use this framework

[Dedexer](http://dedexer.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I don't need to (nor I want to) physically decompile and extract the `.dex`. I only need a **set** of full class names (`Strings`).

Comment: You can also unpack an 'apk' file by using 'tar -xvf <apk_file>'

Answer (score 5):

baksmali has functionality to do this starting in baksmali v2.2.

`baksmali list classes my.dex` will print a list of all classes in the given dex file.

Reference:   It is downloadable from here:   https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali.

Answer (score 0):

dxshow mydexfile.dex

dxshow:

strings -a $1 | grep "^L.*/" | grep -v "Ljava" | grep -v "Landroid" | sed "s/^L\(.*\);/\1/" | sed "s:/:.:g"

ezpz hack... didn't wanna spend a lifetime java coding