# Represent file structure to JSON

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to represent current files structure in JSON or XML code but with some conditions.

- I want to my representation to not mention middle empty directories.
- I want to only list files ended with `Activity.*`

For example:
for this structure

```
my_project
├── feature1
│   └── src
│       └── java
│           └── com
│               └── directory
│                   ├── MainActivity.kt
│                   └── MainFragment.kt
└── feature2
    └── src
        └── java
            └── com
                └── directory
                    ├── Feature2Activity.kt
                    └── Feature2Fragment.kt
```

Should generate

```
{
  "my_project": {
    "feature1": {
      "directory": ["MainActivity"]
    },
    "feature2": {
      "directory": ["Feature2Activity"]
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't matter if I can't do this at runtime, think of it as a script that I will use on directory. Not at runtime of the App.

Comment: Sources (src folder) won't be available at runtime of application, did you mean to list .class files (JVM bytecode) compressed in the dex file (inside apk)?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Thanks!
So is there any other option to do this?

Comment: You can't verify if it was a Java file or Kotlin, you can work out for the files having Activity at their last though.

Comment: Can you please help me do this? I don't care if it's Java or Kotlin.
So what you offer is enough for me

Comment: It doesn't matter if I can't do this at runtime, think of it as a script that I will use on directory. Not at runtime of the App.

Comment: @william wait it is possible I'm writing an answer

Comment: @william by the way which json library are you using?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu Moshi.

Answer (score 1):

The source files are compiled into JVM bytecode and then they are compiled into the Dex (Dalvik Executable) that can run on the Android platform.

You can use the Dex file of your application that can be accessed by the context.

```kotlin
val activityFiles = mutableListOf<String>()

DexFile(context.getPackageCodePath()).entries().apply {
    while(hasMoreElement()) {
        val fileName = nextElement.substringAfterLast('.').substringBefore('$')
        if(fileName.contains("Activity")) activityFiles.add(fileName)
    }
}

// Logic to generate Json. You may use any json library.
val innerJson = mutableMapOf(
    getAppName() to mapOf(
        "directory" to activityFiles
    )
)

// Hard-code the parent project name (holding both sub application)
val jsonRepresentation: MutableMap<String, Any> = mutableMapOf("my_project" to innerJson)

val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()

val json = moshi.adapter(Map::class.java).toJson(jsonRepresentation)


fun getAppName(ctx: Context) {
    val appInfo = context.getApplicationInfo()
    val id = appInfo.labelRes
    return if (id == 0) applicationInfo.nonLocalizedLabel.toString()
    else context.getString(id)
}
```

I wonder if there it is possible to have feature1 info and feature2 both, as you will be having context of that specified application. If you are writing code in `feature1` then won't be able to see classes / app name of the other `feature2`.

References

- https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/dalvik/system/DexFile#entries()
- [Is there a way to get a list of all classes from a .dex file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343388/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-list-of-all-classes-from-a-dex-file)
- [Find all classes in a package in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446036/find-all-classes-in-a-package-in-android)
- [Android - How to get application name? (Not package name)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229219/android-how-to-get-application-name-not-package-name)

Comment: Thanks!
But now I only have list of files .. how can I generate the Json structure that has the parent directories?

Comment: @wiliam wait a minute

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I was looking for using only `kotlin.io` and don't depend on any Android decencies.
Do you think we can achieve our goal with `FileTreeWalk`?

Comment: @wiliam i'd say then just create a gradle task, using the gradle kotlin dsl and run that, that would be cleaner approach when you are having the sources (i.e. when you are compiling)

Comment: I've been using gradle task for that like this: https://imgur.com/a/yBQI7nj